# LaTeX project extension with double menues in vscode

Tags: vscode, latex-workshop

I use the extension "LaTeX Worshop" in Visual Studio Code. It all works fine, but there are two of all kinds of items (like menues). See picture.

[image]

Comment: Welcome TeX.SE @tork73. Isn't your extension installed twice with different names or at different location? Anyway, I think it's an issue with Vscode or the extension and should be reported to them.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I found out that I had also installed TeX Worshop. So removing that extension solved the problem.